# Akka PersistenActor with RoundRobinPool

Tags: akka

I am trying to implement eventsourcing using Akka persisten actors. The receiver actors are persistent, they persist the message before processing them. I have a round-robin-pool of persistent receiver actors. Now since the persistent id is same for these pool of actors, how to handle recovery? Or i want to understand the correct way of using persistency with pool of actors...

I was thinking to use this propery 'akka.persistence.max-concurrent-recoveries = 1'.

NOTE: i am using java

Answer (score 3):

According to docs:

> Note persistenceId must be unique to a given entity in the journal
>   (database table/keyspace). When replaying messages persisted to the
>   journal, you query messages with a persistenceId. So, if two different
>   entities share the same persistenceId, message-replaying behavior is
>   corrupted.

Seems that you need akka `cluster-sharding` with unique `persistenceId` for every entity actor.

Also see:
[Can I Read/Write from separate actors with same PersistenceId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210277/can-i-read-write-from-separate-actors-with-same-persistenceid)

Comment: Thanks. I went through the doc earlier and then I had this doubt. By the way, I do not want to use cluster-sharding, I want to scale the actors with in the same JVM. I think the correct way is to remove persistency on the receiver actos.